# Error while estimating xgboost in h2o after update to 3.18

Tags: r, io, h2o, xgboost

I encountered the known issue of not being able to save the xgboost model and load it later to obtain predictions and it was supposedly changed in h2o 3.18 (the problem was in 3.16). I updated the package from h2o's website (downloadable zip) and now the model that had no problem gives the following error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
```

This is only in the case of xgboost (binary classification), as other models I use work fine. Of course h2o is initialised and a previous model estimates without problems. Does anyone have any idea what can be the issue?

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example (based on Erin's answer) that produces the error:

```
library(h2o)
library(caret)
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome train set into H2O
train <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
y <- "response"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)

# Assigning fold column
set.seed(1)
cv_folds <- createFolds(as.data.frame(train)$response,
                        k = 5,
                        list = FALSE,
                        returnTrain = FALSE)

# version 1
train <- train %>%
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    mutate(fold_assignment = cv_folds) %>%
    as.h2o()

# version 2
train <- h2o.cbind(train, as.h2o(cv_folds))
names(train)[dim(train)[2]] <- c("fold_assignment")


# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])

xgb <- h2o.xgboost(x = x,
                   y = y, 
                   seed = 1,
                   training_frame = train,
                   fold_column = "fold_assignment",
                   keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                   eta = 0.01,
                   max_depth = 3,
                   sample_rate = 0.8,
                   col_sample_rate = 0.6,
                   ntrees = 500,
                   reg_lambda = 0,
                   reg_alpha = 1000,
                   distribution = 'bernoulli')
```

Both versions of creating the train data.frame result in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say whether you have re-trained the models using 3.18.  In general, H2O only guarantees model compatibility between major version of H2O.  If you have not retrained the models, that's probably the reason that XGBoost is not working properly.  If you have re-trained the models with 3.18 and XGBoost is still not working, then please post a reproducible example and we will check it out further.

**EDIT:**
I am adding reproducible example (the only difference from your code and this code is that I am not using `fold_column` here). This runs fine on 3.18.0.2.  Without a reproducible example that produces an error, I can't help you any further.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome train set into H2O
train <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
y <- "response"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])

xgb <- h2o.xgboost(x = x,
                   y = y, 
                   seed = 1,
                   training_frame = train,
                   keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                   eta = 0.01,
                   max_depth = 3,
                   sample_rate = 0.8,
                   col_sample_rate = 0.6,
                   ntrees = 500,
                   reg_lambda = 0,
                   reg_alpha = 1000,
                   distribution = 'bernoulli')
```

Comment: I might not have been clear, but the problem is with estimation in general. So I was able to train the xgboost on a given dataset using h2o 3.16. However, after removing this version and installing 3.18 the training produces the error. In other words, it fails to train the model in a given version, not training the model in one and testing in other. Hope that is clear now.

Comment: I updated my answer with a reproducible example.  I don't have any errors when using XGBoost in H2O 3.18.

Comment: When I add the fold column, the code produces an error. Please find an edited version of the question above.

Comment: New new code you posted above doesn't work because you're trying to use pipes on an H2OFrame which is not supported, and you didn't actually add the "fold_assignment" column to the frame.  
The error will tell you that: `Illegal argument(s) for XGBoost model: XGBoost_model_R_1519597007018_2.  Details: ERRR on field: _fold_column: Fold column 'fold_assignment' not found in the training frame
ERRR on field: _fold_column: Fold column 'fold_assignment' not found in the training frame`

Comment: Actually the pipes do work, the result is an h2o frame with added column. But just to double check I used the `h2o.cbind`: `fold_assignment <- as.h2o(cv_folds)
train <- h2o.cbind(train, fold_assignment)
` which also results in the same error: `Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused`. So I assume that it is not the pipes fault.

Comment: Ok I was finally able to replicate the error, and reported the bug here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5353
Which tidyverse package did you load? (your code is missing the library statement, so I had to guess).  When using `library(tidyverse)` the pipe does not work (which is what I used), but `library(dplyr)` does.   Thx for the bug report, hope to get it fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for your help Erin. I used `dplyr` for the pipe operator.